# 引数が無いかどうか調べる処理をしたい

Tags: python

変数が空かどうかを調べ，空だった場合は途中終了する処理をしたいのですが，どのように書けばいいのでしょうか？test.pyという名前で以下のようなpythonスクリプトを書いて`python test.py`と引数なしで実行したみたのですが，print文に書かれた内容が出力されません．どのように書き直せばいいのでしょうか？また，このような処理に関してより一般的な（エレガントな）方法があれば教えていただきたいです．

```
import sys

aaa = str(sys.argv[1])

if(aaa == ''):
    print('You need args!')
    sys.exit()
else:
    print('input argument is ', aaa)
```

Comment: 私の環境だとこのプログラムを引数無しで実行するとエラー `IndexError: list index out of range` が出るのですが、sketch さんの環境でもエラーが出ますか？

Comment: 「変数が空かどうか調べる処理をしたい」ではなく「引数が無いかどうか調べる処理をしたい」なのかな、と思い回答をしてみました。意図があっていれば題名も併せて変えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: @nekketsuuuさん, 回答ありがとうございます．無事に解決いたしました．私の質問意図はnekketsuuuさんのご指摘の通り「引数が無いかどうか調べる処理をしたいでした」．質問文もあわせて修正しました．

Answer (score 4, accepted):

引数がちゃんと 1 つ以上与えられているか検査するためには、`sys.argv` の内容を直接調べるのでなく引数の長さ (argc) を調べるのが良いでしょう。

```
if(len(sys.argv) <= 1):
    print('You need args!')
    sys.exit()

# ここに到達できていれば sys.argv[1] は必ず存在するので、安全にアクセスできます。
aaa = str(sys.argv[1])
print('input argument is', aaa)
```

---

また、質問文のプログラムは「変数が空文字列かどうか調べる」ことはきちんとできています。試しに `python test.py ''` のように引数として空文字列を与えると、エラーを出さずに `You need args!` を出力します。

根本的な問題は、引数が無いときは `sys.argv[1]` が存在しないことです。このため引数無しで実行すると `IndexError: list index out of range` というエラーが出ます。